# Adding subdomain on Namecheap for Shared IP SiteGround website

Tags: dns, subdomain, namecheap

I have been figuring out how to accomplish this for a day now and read through a bunch of tutorials but could not make it work the way I wanted.

So my current set up is that I have a website that I registered the domain with Namecheap, let's call it `mywebsite.com`. The main app is hosted on Heroku, so both `mywebsite.com` and `www.mywebsite.com` is set up as URL redirect and CNAME to point to the heroku address. For example I have a CNAME record for `www` pointing to `www.mywebsite.com.herokudns.com.` This works fine and I would like to keep it that way.

I recently registered for a SiteGround service to set up my wordpress blog. I would like it to be accessible at `blog.mywebsite.com`. Most of the tutorial I have seen is to either migrate the domain to siteground so the wordpress site can point to the main domain or to point the namecheap DNS nameservers  to the siteground one which I don't want to do neither because I do not want to redirect the traffic away from the heroku app.

I have tried to set up NSRecord according to Namecheap doc, I added the record for `blog` to point to `ns1.siteground1111.com` (the nameservers siteground provided) but when I entered `blog.mywebsite.com` it said server not found. I am on a SiteGround shared IP plan and I can see the blog if I visit `ns1.siteground205.com/~myusername`. However creating A record or CNAME requires bare IP and domain so I wonder if that's the issue.

My question is if my approach was correct in trying to set up the subdomain by creating a NSRecord on Namecheap pointing to SiteGround's nameservers. Or is it necessary for me to pay extra and get a dedicated IP address from SiteGround for me to point my A record for `blog` to.

Alternatively, I also have extra domains I am not using and I could set SiteGround blog to those domains and perhaps create a CNAME record for `blog.mywebsite.com` to `www.myotherwebsite.com`? That sounds like an overcomplication of the issue but I am not sure what to try at this point.

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In Namecheap admin for your domain name mywebsite.com:

(1) Create an A record:

```
[type, host, value, TTL]

A, @, 1.2.3.4, 1min
```

where 1.2.3.4 is the Siteground IP address of your account.

(2) Create another A record:

```
A, blog, 1.2.3.4, Automatic
```